# Double Integral exists or not

Tags: real-analysis

Let $ \Omega :[0,1] \times [0,1] $. Let $f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be $f(x,y) = 1 \ if\ x=0\ and \ y \in \mathbb{Q},\ \ \ 0\ otherwise $.

Which of the following exists, and find the integral if it exists (give reason)

(a) $ \int \int _ \Omega f$

(b) $\int_0^1( \int_0^1 f dx) dy$

(c)$\int_0^1( \int_0^1 f dy) dx$

Comment: please think it as a riemann integral not as lebesque integral

Comment: here is just what i thought, (a) this one exists because the set of points of the function that has discontinuity is measure zero. I am unable to calculate its value
 (c) exists and it value is 0, because i will integrate it except at x=0
(b) i think it exists but i am not sure

Comment: what do you think is the set of discontinuities?

Comment: say D = {(x,y)/x=0 and y is rational}. This is the set and it is countable. so it has measure zero

Comment: not quite. Try to prove that the function is continuous at $(0,\pi)$.

Comment: sorry, it is every where discont. on x=0

Comment: and so it is also not Riemann integrable.

Comment: Why are you talking about measure of the set if you think of this as Riemann integral not Lebesgue integral?